# Can Eclipse (Kepler) select between two installed MinGW distributions when setting a Toolchain?

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I was working with **Eclipse Kepler** and I was using one of many **MinGW** distributions that you can find in internet. So, yesterday I decide to install **QTCreator**. But when I finished the QTcreator's installation process I tryed to create a new project in **Eclipse**, and now I'm not able to select other **MinGW** toolchain than the installed by Qt SDK.

Is like **MinGW** installation of **QtSDK** shadows my other **MinGW** installation.

What I'm missing? Can Eclipse select between two installed MinGW distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can!!!

When a project is created and is set to use the MinGW toolchain you can modify the environment variables for the project. There is a env variable called  `MINGW_HOME` oh, thats rings a bell.

Right click on the project and select properties (or select the project and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Enter</kbd>), follow the path:  `C/C++ Build -> Environment` and then change the variable value to the installation path of the mingw distribution you want to use for your project.

[image: Selecting a MinGW distribution for the project]

you can choose between `Append variables to native environment` or `Replace native environment with specified one`.